# Select all the components of a array without a loop

Tags: java, arrays, listener

I've made a array full of `JLabels` and would like to add a listener to them.

The listener doesn't need to know exactly which one was clicked on, just that one was.
Is there a way to add the listener to the whole array instead of using a 'for()' loop ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: why you want to avoid using a for loop? Btw I don't think there are other ways..

Comment: dont be so mean to the for(). its there to help you. use it!

Comment: Well, if there was another way, it would make my code a lot lighter, so I was wondering.

Comment: lighter? In what terms?
a *for* loop is really simple in RTL instructions implementation..

Comment: Just add the listener upon `JLabel`  creation!!!

Comment: The problem I was thinking about was my MouseClicked(event), because I had it checking what component is calling it with some if(component.isFocusOwner()). I believed I could use for to generate a huge number of 'if(component.isFocusOwner())' but it doesn't work (I'm probably just doing it wrong). I will solve this by creating a new class that contain a MouseListener only used by the array's JLabels, so there won't have any check for who got the focus. That'll have me changing the way my application work, that's why I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Comment: Fixed : isFocusOwner wasn't the right thing (it worked until then >.< ). Oscar Reyes' getSource() did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your labels are added a to a container ( like a JPanel ) you can add a listener to this container and know which component is at certain location.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.addMouseListener( whichOneListener );
f.setContentPane( panel );
```

In this case I use a mouseListener because that give me the location where the user clicked.

```
private static MouseListener whichOneListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
        JComponent c = ( JComponent ) e.getSource();
        JLabel l  = ( JLabel ) c.getComponentAt( e.getPoint() );
        System.out.println( l.getText() );
    }

};
```

And prints correctly what component was clicked.

The full source code is [here](http://pastebin.com/f1e75059f)

Answer (score 3):

No there is no out of the box solution, AFAIK. Apart from using stupid hacks, I think you may have to use a for loop, and it may be a 10 line code, nothing to worry about.

Comment: *.. Apart from using stupid hacks....* Or you can learn the library you're using and the options it offers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693436/select-all-the-components-of-a-array-without-a-loop/1693675#1693675

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your array of JLabels in a class and implement your own Add() method which registers the listener upon adding them.

This way you wouldn't have to iterate over them afterwards..

Answer (score 1):

Yyou can register the listener on the JPanel (or whatever component the buttons are in) so you only have to write a single listener.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a list of JLabels, I'd suggest using [CollectionUtils.forAllDo](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#forAllDo%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Closure%29) - method which allows you to apply same action to a bunch of objects.